# Error: y could not convert string to float python random forests

Tags: python, random-forest, prediction

I am using Python and random forests to predict the first column of my input file, my input file is under the form of:

```
T,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
N,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Here is the link to my full data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gjKoSi4rmMYZVm31LZ2Li92HM9USlu6A/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to predict the first column either T or N, depending on the values of the remaining columns and I am using random forests. I am getting the following error, how to fix it? Here is the code:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset = pd.read_csv( 'data1extended.txt', sep= ',') 
dataset.head()
row_count, column_count = dataset.shape
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=20, random_state=0)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your target variable to numeric first.  Assuming 'gold' column is your target, run this immediately after loading the data to a dataframe.

```
dataset['gold'] = dataset['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: I recieve the error message: ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

Comment: You have a problem in your input data.  One of the rows is broken.  https://imgur.com/yBBRyiO

Comment: i have fixed the file and I still receive the same error even with a fixed file, try removing some lines and test the code just with the 10 first lines of the input file and you will see that the same error still occurs